# az devops: Login with command line

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to login to azure devops by command line to publish my packages in artifact universal packages

I generated my personal access token and I am trying to run the following command:

```
echo "XXXXXXXX" | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/XYZ/
```

I am not sure if I have to use the general access token encrypted in base64

When I use the unencrypted general access token I get the following message

> Failed to store PAT using keyring; falling back to file storage. You
> can clear the stored credential by running az devops logout. Refer
> https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth to know more on sign in with PAT.

And when i use the general access token in base64 I get:

```
Failed to authenticate using the supplied token
```

This is my version of az cli:

```
azure-cli                         2.46.0

core                              2.46.0
telemetry                          1.0.8

Extensions:
azure-devops                      0.26.0

Dependencies:
msal                              1.20.0
azure-mgmt-resource             21.1.0b1
```

The token has all access and I can use to publish in npm without errors but I don't know why I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to log in using the variable
`AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT` (the general access token that should be unencrypted):

```
export AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT=XXXXXX
```

Then I no longer need to use the `az devops login` command and I can use the command:

```
az artifacts universal XXXXX
```